# Add a table in a wordpress article using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress

Using jQuery in a Wordpress article/page (without break-line and in jQuery's Compatibility Mode), why can I insert any plain text, but not DIRECTLY a html `tag` for example a `<p>` or a `<table>` using appropriate jQuery method (html)?

For example, in Wordpress, the following code doesn't work:

```js
$(".div_import_text").html("New text");
$(".div_import_table").html("<table><tr><th><p>1</p></th><th><p>2</p></th></tr><tr><td>A</td> <td>B</td></tr></table>");
```

```css
table, tr, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="div_import_text">Old text</div>
<div class="div_import_table">Old table</div>
```

There are non problems, however, to insert formatted text and html tags INDIRECTLY (for example, by copying it from another Wordpress  page/article, for example using the jQuery method `get`). Why? Is it for safety reasons, as seems to say this post? https://stackoverflow.com/a/2075942/7208844

So why allow the INDIRECT inclusion of content by importing it from other Wordpress page through the jQuery method `get` mentioned?

Sorry for the long question and thanks for your time.

Comment: did you check the console?

Comment: Yes, there is no error. If I use a tag `<p>` nothing appears; if I use `&lt;p&gt;` appears `<p>`. So, I think it depends by safety reasons. The content imported from another page is sanitized. What do you think?

Comment: you are getting your html from a external source via ajax?

Comment: No, in the same wordpress page. 
to be precise, the same table to be copied in different `divs`.

Comment: then this should be no problem with security

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress seems to add each html element from a string to a new line which breaks the javascript, i suggest you create a custom shortcode with your javascript and append that to your post

Comment: Sorry (for my bad english), I do not see the table (content) on wordpress page, neither errors in the console

Comment: is the div_import_table on the page ,is it visible ??

Comment: No, the DOM shows the empty `div` (with old content)

Comment: Yes, thank you for your interest and your time. How can I do it?

Comment: Thanks, I try it immediately :-)

Comment: No, it doesn't work. Jquery's compatibility mode requires:
`<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
//jQuery code
});
</script>`

Comment: did the syntax from your comment work, any new console errors?

Comment: Nothing appears. Is it sanitized by wordpress code? 
I will not steal any more your time, thank you again for your kindness.

Comment: how do you call this code from a php file via script tag or from a js file in a wordpress function ?

Comment: The jQuery code is in the same wordpress page of the `div` and it is in a `script` tag.

Comment: @juri Do you see your actual jQuery code in the page source?

Comment: Yes, I see it in the page source (and in the DOM using console).

Comment: Try with a demo wordpress: https://demos1.softaculous.com/WordPress/2016/12/14/stackoverflow/
Admin Username: admin
Admin Password: pass

Comment: better create a custom shortcode with your javascript

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way: I published the `<table>` in another wordpress page and then I imported it in the `<div>` using the jQuery method `get`.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 $.get("external-wordpress-page",function(res){ 
  $(".table").html($(res).find('.table'));
 },'html');
})
</script>
```

Thank you all anyway